# Android Google Maps passing multiple destinations

Tags: android, google-maps

How to pass single sources address and multiple destinations in Google map in this code?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34 daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/San+Jose,+CA/GooglePlex/San+Francisco,+CA"));
```

if you try to share a page with 2 or more destination, this is what Google returns:

> https://www.google.com/maps/dir/fromAddress/toAddress1/toAddress2

[image]

Opening the intent on Android device, the destination field would be your first toAddress, but the route itself is correct.

[image]

Does not seem to work on iOS by the way.